# how to tslint error in angular 6 using service?

Tags: angular, typescript

I make a service and used that service in component .mY code is working fine .But I am getting `tslint` error why ?
 function on which I am getting error

```
getUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>> {
    return this.http.get<UserModel>(this.configUrl).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

**code**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4pkct8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuserdetail.service.ts

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast response like this -

```
getUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>> {
return this.http.get<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(this.configUrl).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
 );
}
```

Comment: thanks my error is removed But still I am getting error on `this.handleError` function .see my update

Comment: do you have any idea

Comment: on Stackblitz everything working fine without any error

Comment: but on `webstrom editor` it is giving me `lint error` see screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You are type casting your `http.get` to `<UserModel>`, but your method expects you to return `Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>>`.

Change to method signatures return value to `Observable<UserModel>` so they match.

```
getUsers(): Observable<UserModel> {
  return this.http.get<UserModel>(this.configUrl).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks my error is removed But still I am getting error on `this.handleError` function .see my update

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because "throwerror()" returns an `Observable<never>`

You are returning two different types one on success (`Observable<UserModel>`) and one on error (`Observable<never>`).

The below would stop your error showing albeit maybe not having the result you want

```
getUsers(): Observable<HttpResponse<UserModel>> | Observable<never> {
   return this.http.get<HttpResponse<UserModel>>(this.configUrl).pipe(
     catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

}